# メタでの信用度が更新されない?

Tags: バグ, 完了

<sub>[@akiraak](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/37/akiraak)さんに代わって報告します:</sub>

@akiraakさんは[メインサイトでの信用度が 6 になったものの](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/37/akiraak)、メタでは 1 のままです。そのため、信用度が足りずメタで質問をすることができません。「質問する」ボタンを押すと、

> メタで質問をするには、少なくとも 5 点の信用度が スタック・オーバーフロー で必要です。

と表示されます。

メタでの信用度が更新されないのはバグでしょうか。

Comment: entoは全部探してしまうね（笑）これは今日気づいて開発者に投げました。サイトの状況（プライベートベータ前）で複数の問題が発生するらしいです。とりあえず解決方法は検討中です。

Comment: @jmac これに関しては[tomuteさんの指摘](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/158/)が先です =)

Comment: @jmac 翻訳されてない箇所を４つほど投稿したいのですが書き込めない状態です。忘れないうちに投稿してしまいたいのですが、メインの方に書いてしまって後で管理者権限でメタに移動してもらうのでよいですか？

Comment: @akiraak大丈夫ですよ！